# NSXMLParser multiple call - BAD ACCESS

Tags: iphone, delegates, nsxmlparser, exc-bad-access

hello i want to parse html an with this information another html file...
after 1-5 call the program crashes...

header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <ZBarReaderDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate>{

    UIImageView *resultImage;
    UITextView *resultText;
    NSString *product_link;
    NSXMLParser *parseHTML;
    NSXMLParser *parseHTML2;
    NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;
    id <NSXMLParserDelegate> testkollege, asdf;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *resultImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *resultText;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet NSString *product_link;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSXMLParser *parseHTML;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSXMLParser *parseHTML2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <NSXMLParserDelegate> testkollege;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <NSXMLParserDelegate> asdf;
- (IBAction) scanButtonTapped;

@end
```

m-file:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSDebug.h"

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize resultImage, resultText;
@synthesize product_link;
@synthesize parseHTML, parseHTML2;

@synthesize myMutableArray;
@synthesize testkollege, asdf;

bool link_is_here = false;
bool allergy_is_here = false; 
bool parse_one_ok = true;

- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{

    // ADD: get the decode results
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)
        // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
        break;

    // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode data
    resultText.text = symbol.data;    
    // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode image
    resultImage.image =
    [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // ADD: dismiss the controller (NB dismiss from the *reader*!)
    [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

    parseHTML = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://url.com/suche/?q=" stringByAppendingString:symbol.data]] ];  
    NSLog(@"parser 1 start");
    [parseHTML setDelegate:self];
    [parseHTML parse]; 
    NSLog(@"parser 1 ready");
    [parseHTML release];

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    for(NSString *key in [attributeDict allKeys]) {
        if ([[attributeDict valueForKey:key] isEqualToString:@"search-result"]) {
            link_is_here = true;        
        }
        if ([key isEqualToString:@"href"] && link_is_here) {
            product_link = [attributeDict valueForKey:key];
            [parser abortParsing];
            parseHTML2 = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://url.com" stringByAppendingString:product_link]]];
            [parseHTML2 setDelegate:self];
            parse_one_ok = true;
            link_is_here = false;
            [parseHTML2 parse];

        }
        if ([key isEqualToString:@"id"] && [[attributeDict valueForKey:key] isEqualToString:@"nutrition-allergy"]) {
            allergy_is_here = true;
        }
        if ([key isEqualToString:@"title"] && allergy_is_here) {      
            NSLog(@"keys:  %@",[attributeDict valueForKey:key]);  
        }
        if ([key isEqualToString:@"id"] && [[attributeDict valueForKey:key] isEqualToString:@"another string"]) {
            allergy_is_here = false;
            parse_one_ok = true;
            NSLog(@"Parser off");
            [parser abortParsing];
        } 
    }
}
-(void) parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    if (parse_one_ok) {

        [parseHTML2 release];
        parse_one_ok = false;
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

}  

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [parseHTML release];
    [parseHTML2 release];
    self.product_link = nil;
    self.resultImage = nil;
    self.resultText = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: you need to show us the crash log

Comment: If it's a bad access and he doesn't have zombies enabled, there won't be a useful crash log.

Comment: Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer-old/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3 (8F190)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).

Answer (score 1):

that is simple. You are releasing ParseHTML NSXMLPArsetwice.

1. -(void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
   in the lastline
2. -(void)dealloc.

A object should be release only if you have earned the ownership. by retain copy etc. But you have allocated  it only once so should release only once. But you did two releases .

You are also releasing NSXMLParser object parseHTML2 thrice. As per your code at any stage parseHTML2 will be released at least twice which is retained only once. ParseHTML1  objects case have been mentioned above

Regards,
Jackson Sunny Rodrigues

Comment: hello @Jackson Sunny Rodrigues, thank you for this hint, i commented it, but there is still bad access... :(

Answer (score 0):

Turn on NSZombieEnabled.  You are obviously releasing something you shouldn't be.  When you do this, it will show you exactly where the bad access is occurring and you can trace back to where you are releasing the object.  Check out this tutorial:

http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone

Best to learn how to fix it and what's wrong :)

Comment: i tried to see with NSZombieEnabled more... but there is no further information...

Comment: Enable your breakpoints.  It should trip when you try to access the released object.

Comment: In Xcode, there is a button to enable breakpoints in your project.  I am not sure if they have to be enabled or not to make zombies trip.  Give it a shot?

Comment: i got this now: unable to load symbol file: (gdb)

Comment: i just need an abort, close, exit or something to stop all parser and everything would be ok..

Comment: i tried everything with nszombie etc... i have no idea any more... sometimes it works 4 times in a row...